# Wordpress как правильно вывести авторизацию/регистрацию?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть плагин digits, он нужен для создания регистрации по номеру телефона и не только.
Он, отлично выполняет свою работу.

Вот так он добавляет это на странице оформления заказов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне нужно сдеалать:
При пролистывании страницы магазина, на определённом моменте вывести модальное окно, в котором будет предложено авторизоваться/зарегистрироваться и другая инфа (вам будет выдана скидка и т.п.).

Попробовал пару плагинов, остановился на WP Popups — WordPress Popup builder. Я его настроил, вывод сделал, всё работает, но кроме текста нужно добавить как-то эту самую авторизацию/регистрацию.

Если я выведу через "WP_login_form();" (Вывожу через шорткод, предварительно сам его создаю в functions.php, так-как в редакторе плагина нельзя использовать php). То получается следующее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, нету номера телефона и получение кода.

У самого плагина digits есть своё модальное окно. Но его нельзя вывести. Есть шорткоды, которые добавляют кнопку, нажав на которую откроется модальное окно. Но мне же нужно что-бы открывалось не при клике же.

Можете пробовать тут - https://wolf.richgo.ru/shop (нужно пролистать чуть ниже и появится окошко).
Так-же заметил кое-что. Если в этом самом модальном окне (пробуйте сами) выделить логин или пароль, то окно закроется. Но если удалять через кнопку на клавиатуре, всё хорошо.
Так-же, если удалить логин через кнопку на клавиатуре, а потом написать любую цифру, то появится выбор кода страны и в принципе форма ввода станет другой, для номера телефона.

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Чем плох этот? Я попытался сделать максимально понятным.

Comment: Он плох тем, что его невозможно воспроизвести - надо установить пару плагинов, которые непонятно, где брать, потом догадаться, каким кодом вы выводите шорткод. Хотите, чтобы вам ответили - облегчите задачу. И прочитайте правила создания вопросов по ссылке ещё раз, они не просто так написаны.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.